# How to set -Xss in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, stack-size

My problem is that I want to increase the default stack size when running a Java project in Eclipse. I've tried looking for the answer, and it looks like I need to set the -Xss option to a larger number, but I don't know how to access/set this value.

I'm on a Windows machine, running Eclipse 3.6.0. How would I set this option? I guess, specifically, I'm asking for the *steps* for how I could

1. find out what the default value for the stack size is, and
2. set that value to something higher.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All default parameters to Eclipse can be ovewritten in the configuration file eclipse.ini, including the heap size.

see  http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_increase_the_heap_size_available_to_Eclipse%3F

Comment: Changing the values in the config.ini file doesn't work for me. I still get StackOverflowError unless I set the Xss directly in the runAs configuration.

Answer (score 2):

In the DebugAs configuration, put the value into the JVM options box.

That answers #2. I don't know the answer to #1.

Comment: Thank you VERY much! I was looking all over Eclipse to find that!